# Firebase neither give callback nor error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am retrieving data from firebase database.

When I debug the code from simulator it gives all the data from that node but when i debug the code from device it neither goes to success block nor error block. Nothing happens.

Code I have written is given below.

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("registeredUserEmail").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        debugPrint(snapshot.value)
        if snapshot.hasChild(email.escapeEmail()) {
            debugPrint("false")
            completion(false)
        }
        else {
            debugPrint("true")
            completion(true)
        }
    }) { (error) in
        debugPrint("error in isEmailFree - " + error.localizedDescription)
        completion(false)
    }
```

Here are the console logs when app first time launches

2016-06-07 11:36:30.471[4067:1092564] Configuring the default app.
2016-06-07 11:36:30.530[4067:]  Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
2016-06-07 11:36:30.532 Artup[4067:]  To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
2016-06-07 11:36:30.576[4067:1092564] Firebase Crash Reporting: Successfully enabled
2016-06-07 11:36:30.590:  FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-06-07 11:36:30.659 Artup[4067:]  Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
Config not fetched
Error Error Domain=com.google.remoteconfig.ErrorDomain Code=8002 "(null)" UserInfo={error_throttled_end_time_seconds=1465279698.4105051}
2016-06-07 11:36:31.450 Artup[4067:]  Firebase Analytics enabled

Comment: what are your console logs

Comment: In the above code none of the message are printed. Console log is clear.

Comment: some other logs of firebase might be there in the log.

Comment: Hey @Shubhank I have edited the question.Please check out the console logs when app first time launches

Comment: is the method in which you are calling this even being called ?

Comment: Yes, actually i am calling this method at textFieldDidEndEditing method. This code works fine in the simulator but when I tried to run with device none of the completion handler are called.

Comment: I tried with another device then it works there.What is the problem with that device? Or this might be due to persistenceEnabled = true in firebase so that it does not connect to database. I don't understand this problem.

Comment: are the device OS version different ?

Comment: yes, It runs successfully in IOS 9.3 and do not runs in IOS 9.3.2

Comment: it may be a upgrade issue that broke FCM.

Comment: what will be the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From other Firebase products on iOS and from the UserInfo bit, I think the request is being throttled. Firebase remote config will throttle your requests — I can't speak for the database, however. I don't see anything in the Firebase documentation about this but it seems likely the cause of this error.

Answer (score 1):

From the error logs it looks like the error is coming directly from a RemoteConfig fetch. Is this being instrumented somewhere in your app delegate?

Right at the end of of your log the following part is of interest. `{error_throttled_end_time_seconds=1465279698.4105051}`. This time translates to **Jun 7, 2016, 4:08 PM**. Now at first this looks like a throttling expiry of 4.5 hours but this is unlikely. This is time is most likely in UTC and you would have to adjust this to your local timezone of your logging **2016-06-07 11:36:30.471**

A 30 mins throttling sound about right. Unfortunately, I cannot find documentation around the strict rules around throttling.